# How to get the mentioned users from react draft-js-mention-plugin?

Tags: draftjs, draft-js-plugins

I gone through the documentation of draft-js-mention-plugin but couldn't figure a way to read all the mentions from the content. Is there a way can find all the mentions as array?. I need to store all the mentions seperately and send email.Your help is highly appreciated. I am using the example given in [here](https://www.draft-js-plugins.com/plugin/mention)

Answer (score 4):

You can do like below :

```
const rawEditorContent = convertToRaw(this.state.editorState.getCurrentContent());
const entityMap = rawEditorContent.entityMap;
enter code here
```

Then loop through entityMap to get mentioned users:

```
Object.values(entityMap).map(entity => {
    console.log(entity.data.mention);
});
```